# Identifying bull and bear markets of an asset

Tags: python, pandas

Bear markets start when the security price declines by 20% or more from its 52-week high and end when the security price increases by 20% or more from its recent low.

Example:
I am using yahoo finance to download the SP500. The ticker is "ES=F"

**df = yfinance.download(tickers="ES=F", start="1990-1-1")**

I need to determine:
1)the start date of the bear market
2)the peak
3)the end date of the bear market
4)the trough

Here is what I tried:

```
#Bear market
max_drawdown = 20

#Get dataframe
start = "1990-1-1"
df = yf.download(tickers="ES=F", start=start)

#Get the drawdown

df["Peak"] = df.Close.rolling(window=252).max()
df["Trough"] = df.Close.rolling(window=21).min()
df["Peak_To_Trough"] = 100*(df.Trough / df.Peak -1)

#Get the start date for the recent peak and the end date for the recent trough
alues = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    if math.isnan(df.Peak.iloc[i]): 
        value = np.nan
    else:
        value = df.Close[df.Close == df.Peak.iloc[i]].index[0]
    values.append(value)
df["Start_Date"] = values
df['Start_Date'] = df['Start_Date'].astype('datetime64[ns]')

values = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    if math.isnan(df.Trough.iloc[i]): 
        value = np.nan
    else:
        value = df.Close[df.Close == df.Trough.iloc[i]].index[-1]
    values.append(value)
df["End_Date"] = values
df['End_Date'] = df['End_Date'].astype('datetime64[ns]')

#Filter the bear markets
idx = np.where( (df.Peak_To_Trough<-max_drawdown))              
df = df.iloc[idx]

#Get the duration of the bear markets
df["Num_Days"] = (df.End_Date - df.Start_Date).dt.days

cols =["Start_Date","Peak","End_Date","Trough","Peak_To_Trough","Num_Days"]

#Putting all together
df = df[cols]

#Remove duplicates
df = df.drop_duplicates(['Start_Date','End_Date','Num_Days'],keep = 'first')
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: added the second option, without reference to 52 weeks. Only percentage price movement is used.

Comment: updated the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem in this situation. Let's say there was an upward breakdown, but the prices are low enough in relation to the 52-week high, which will simultaneously give a sell signal to the generated buy signal (if it's not clear, then let me know, I'll show you visually).
In this situation, I can offer the following options:

1. Take the first signal based on the 52 week extremum when it is exceeded by 20%. Subsequent signals should be considered only in excess of 20%, not focusing on 52 weekly extremes.
2. Consider only 20% of the movement initially and subsequently.

Now for the code. Reset index for convenience
work with an index of type int. An array ddd is created, in which the first index is the start time of the trend, the second is the peak or bottom time, the third trend type 1 is bullish, 2 is bearish. In the body of the if trend != '' statement, the peak and bottom are updated. To avoid the situation that I described at the beginning, conditions were added:

```
df.loc[i, '52Lindex'] < df.loc[i, '52Hindex']
df.loc[i, '52Lindex'] > df.loc[i, '52Hindex']
```

This allows you to avoid the situation when two conditions are triggered at the same time, but sometimes the signals arrive with a delay waiting for the condition.
After the cycle is completed, the date is again put by the index.

Drawing data:

1.Green dot is a peak, a triangle is the beginning of a bullish trend.

2.The red dot is the bottom, the triangle is the beginning of a bearish trend.

3.The cross marks the border of index 251.

```
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

max_drawdown = 20
start = "1990-1-1"
df = yf.download(tickers="ES=F", start=start)


df['52H'] = df['Close'].rolling(window=252).max()
df['52L'] = df['Close'].rolling(window=252).min()
df = df.reset_index()
df['52Hindex'] = df['Close'].rolling(window=252).apply(lambda x: x.idxmax())
df['52Lindex'] = df['Close'].rolling(window=252).apply(lambda x: x.idxmin())

x = len(df)
trend = ''
Peak = -np.inf
Trough = np.inf

ddd = np.empty((0, 3), np.datetime64)

for i in range(251, x):
    if trend == 'bear' or trend == '':
        up = (df.loc[df.index[i], 'Close'] - df.loc[df.index[i], '52L']) / (df.loc[df.index[i], '52L'] / 100.0)
        if up >= max_drawdown and df.loc[i, '52Lindex'] < df.loc[i, '52Hindex']:
            trend = 'bull'
            ddd = np.append(ddd, np.array([[df.loc[i, 'Date'], 0, 1]]), axis=0)
            Trough = np.inf
    if trend == 'bull' or trend == '':
        dn = (df.loc[df.index[i], '52H'] - df.loc[df.index[i], 'Close']) / (df.loc[df.index[i], '52H'] / 100.0)
        if dn >= max_drawdown and df.loc[i, '52Lindex'] > df.loc[i, '52Hindex']:
            trend = 'bear'
            ddd = np.append(ddd, np.array([[df.loc[i, 'Date'], 0, 2]]), axis=0)
            Peak = -np.inf
    if trend != '':
        if trend == 'bull' and df.loc[i, 'Close'] > Peak:
            Peak = df.loc[i, 'Close']
            ddd[len(ddd) - 1, 1] = df.loc[i, 'Date']
        if trend == 'bear' and df.loc[i, 'Close'] < Trough:
            Trough = df.loc[i, 'Close']
            ddd[len(ddd) - 1, 1] = df.loc[i, 'Date']


df = df.set_index('Date')
up_trend_s = ddd[ddd[:, 2] == 1, 0]
up_trend_f = ddd[ddd[:, 2] == 1, 1]
dn_trend_s = ddd[ddd[:, 2] == 2, 0]
dn_trend_f = ddd[ddd[:, 2] == 2, 1]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.index, df['Close'])
ax.plot(up_trend_s, df.loc[up_trend_s, 'Close'], '^', color='lime')
ax.plot(up_trend_f, df.loc[up_trend_f, 'Close'], 'o', color='lime', markersize=4)
ax.plot(dn_trend_s, df.loc[dn_trend_s, 'Close'], 'v', color='red')
ax.plot(dn_trend_f, df.loc[dn_trend_f, 'Close'], 'o', color='red', markersize=4)
ax.plot(df.index[251], df.loc[df.index[251], 'Close'], 'x', color='red', markersize=10)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

**Update 02.07.2022(option 2, where only percentage price movement is taken into price, with the addition of local peak and bottom). Also added visualization code for 52 weekly highs, lows and their percentage price differences.**

```
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

start = "1990-1-1"
df = yf.download(tickers="AAPL", start=start)

df = df.reset_index()

max_drawdown = 20
x = len(df)
trend = ''
Peak = -np.inf
date_Peak = 0
Trough = np.inf
date_Trough = 0
ddd = np.empty((0, 3), np.datetime64)

for i in range(0, x):
    up = 0
    dn = 0
    if trend == '' or trend == 'bull':
        if df.loc[i, 'Close'] >= Peak:
            Peak = df.loc[i, 'Close']
            date_Peak = df.loc[i, 'Date']
    if trend == '' or trend == 'bear':
        if df.loc[i, 'Close'] <= Trough:
            Trough = df.loc[i, 'Close']
            date_Trough = df.loc[i, 'Date']
    if Peak != -np.inf:
        dn = (Peak - df.loc[df.index[i], 'Close']) / (Peak / 100.0)
    if Trough != np.inf:
        up = (df.loc[df.index[i], 'Close'] - Trough) / (Trough / 100.0)

    if up >= max_drawdown:
        trend = 'bull'
        ddd = np.append(ddd, np.array([[date_Trough, df.loc[i, 'Date'], 1]]), axis=0)
        Trough = np.inf
        Peak = df.loc[df.index[i], 'Close']
        date_Peak = df.loc[i, 'Date']
    if dn >= max_drawdown:
        trend = 'bear'
        ddd = np.append(ddd, np.array([[date_Peak, df.loc[i, 'Date'], 2]]), axis=0)
        Peak = -np.inf
        Trough = df.loc[df.index[i], 'Close']
        date_Trough = df.loc[i, 'Date']


df = df.set_index('Date')
up_trend_s = ddd[ddd[:, 2] == 1, 0]
up_trend_f = ddd[ddd[:, 2] == 1, 1]
dn_trend_s = ddd[ddd[:, 2] == 2, 0]
dn_trend_f = ddd[ddd[:, 2] == 2, 1]

if ddd[len(ddd) - 1, 2] == 1:#if the trend is growing, then we are looking for a local maximum
    ind = up_trend_f[len(up_trend_f) - 1]#get the index of the beginning of the bullish trend
    imax = df.loc[ind:, 'Close'].idxmax()#local maximum
    if df.loc[imax, 'Close'] > df.loc[ind, 'Close']:#if the high is greater than the price of the beginning of the bullish trend, then add a peak
        dn_trend_s = np.append(dn_trend_s, imax)
else:
    ind = dn_trend_f[len(dn_trend_f) - 1]#bear market
    imin = df.loc[ind:, 'Close'].idxmin()
    if df.loc[imin, 'Close'] < df.loc[ind, 'Close']:
        up_trend_s = np.append(up_trend_s, imin)



fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.index, df['Close'])
ax.plot(up_trend_s, df.loc[up_trend_s, 'Close'], 'x', color='lime')
ax.plot(up_trend_f, df.loc[up_trend_f, 'Close'], 'o', color='lime', markersize=4)
ax.plot(dn_trend_s, df.loc[dn_trend_s, 'Close'], 'x', color='red')
ax.plot(dn_trend_f, df.loc[dn_trend_f, 'Close'], 'o', color='red', markersize=4)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

The following code renders the 52 week high(red), high minus max_drawdown(gold), low(green), low plus max_drawdown(pink). In this visualization, you can see how the price simultaneously crosses both the high minus max_drawdown and the low plus max_drawdown.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

start = "1990-1-1"
df = yf.download(tickers="AAPL", start=start)

max_drawdown = 20

df['52H'] = df['Close'].rolling(window=252).max()
df['52L'] = df['Close'].rolling(window=252).min()

df.loc[df.index[251]:, '52H-'] = df.loc[df.index[251]:, '52H'] - (
            (df.loc[df.index[251]:, '52H'] / 100.0) * max_drawdown)
df.loc[df.index[251]:, '52L+'] = df.loc[df.index[251]:, '52L'] + (
            (df.loc[df.index[251]:, '52L'] / 100.0) * max_drawdown)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.index, df['Close'])
ax.plot(df.index[251:], df.loc[df.index[251]:, '52H'], color='red')
ax.plot(df.index[251:], df.loc[df.index[251]:, '52L'], color='green')
ax.plot(df.index[251:], df.loc[df.index[251]:, '52H-'], color='gold')
ax.plot(df.index[251:], df.loc[df.index[251]:, '52L+'], color='magenta')
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Just to be sure. You said: "In this situation, I can offer the following options:

1.Take the first signal based on the 52 week extremum when it is exceeded by 20%. Subsequent signals should be considered only in excess of 20%, not focusing on 52 weekly extremes.
2.Consider only 20% of the movement initially and subsequently." In your code, did you opt for option 1 or option 2? Thanks

Comment: In your code, the cross marks the border of index 251 and you get the bear market start, not the peak at the beginning of the loop.

Comment: I tried out the code for BTC-USD df = yf.download(tickers="BTC-USD",end ="2017-1-1") and you can see dn_trend_s[1] = dn_trend_f[1].. Not sure where the issue comes from.

Comment: If you try  max_drawdown = 15
start = "1990-1-1"
df = yf.download(tickers="CVX", start=start), you will see that the last bottom is not detected despite the fact that CVX is down more than 15% from all-time high. Cannot figure why.

Comment: @BorisMikanikrezai In this code, I used 52 weekly extremes and a 20% rebound in their prices(that is, not the first and not the second options). But this is not a good option. If we consider the algorithm, then an input situation arises, that is, it is likely that the opposite condition is also observed. Here is a picture showing how it happens.![picture](https://imgur.com/a/4nEehjB).

Comment: Therefore, especially when using small values of max_drawdown, this situation arises. To avoid this, I tried to filter transactions. For example, buy, the minimum index must be less than the maximum index (df.loc[i, '52Lindex'] < df.loc[i, '52Hindex']). But, this is also not a good option when there is a buy signal, and the high index is less than the low. The signal is triggered with a delay.
Therefore, I suggested which option 1 or 2. Which one do you choose?

Comment: In the picture, do not pay attention to the dates, this is for clarity. Let's assume this happens within 52 weeks.

Comment: I guess option 1.

Comment: Okay, I'll do it in a few days. Have you tried running the second one?

Comment: I have been playing with the second one. The red dot is no longer the bottom but the beginning of a bearish trend. I tried it out for AAPL. Max drawdown = 20. While it captured the peak (red triangle), the start of the bearish trend (red dot), it does not capture the bottom at the end. But the option 2 looks more robust than your first option and a fortiori, incredibly better than my initial broken code. I thought it would be easy to implement but it turns out that the algorithm to implement is more complex than at the first glance!

Comment: The dot is the entrance. The triangle shows tops and peaks. Increase markersize=9 at the points and you will see that sometimes they are hidden behind the triangle.

Comment: where exactly at AAPL, on what date is the display incorrect? I need to understand. It's possible that I missed something somewhere.

Comment: To be more precise, the red triangle is the top, the red dot is the beginning of the bear market, the green triangle is the bottom, the green dot is the beginning of the bull market (the end of the bear market).

Comment: Using the option 2,  up_trend_s returns the bottom. The last value of  up_trend_s is Timestamp('2020-09-18 00:00:00'). So there is one value missing (the most recent one), which should be Timestamp('2022-06-16 00:00:00').

Comment: On this date, the market is still bearish, there is no upward reversal. Therefore, the bottom has not yet been marked. If necessary, can you make it show the current bottom or peak, depending on what is at the moment? And there is still a bottom in 2020.09, it is barely visible beyond the red dot, since the bearish entry coincided with the bottom and the beginning of the bull market in 2020.12.

Comment: Yes good point. But ideally, we should see a "hypothetical" bottom if the last point is below the point at the beginning of the bearish trend. Same issue with peak. Example: df = yf.download(tickers="JNJ",) - although JNJ trades at a 52-week high, the peak is not captured by the algorithm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246103/discussion-between-inquirer-and-boris-mikanikrezai).